# Режим интеграции экрана VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Хост система Win7. Виртуалка(VirtualBox 5.0.20) Linux mint. Включил режим интеграции экрана, разместил Панель задач windows слева, а аналогичную панель linux(gnome) справа. Когда переключаюсь на приложение windows панель задач(linux) перекрывается. Как бы ограничить максимальный размер окно приложений win или еще какое-нибудь решение чтобы всегда были видны обе панели задач?